# GNU Readline library source code

Tags: gcc, readline

I am trying to modify source code of the GNU Readline library in order to better undestrand how it works. I downloaded version 2.0 [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/) and added an assert(0) statement inside `rl_bind_key` function in `bind.c` but it still works when I call this function in my program (main.c):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "readline.h"
#include "history.h"

int main()
{
    char* input, shell_prompt[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int val = rl_bind_key('\t', rl_complete);
        printf(">> %d\n", val);
    }
    input = readline(shell_prompt);
    if (!input)
    break;
    add_history(input);

}
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: Are you sure you are linking with your modified version of the library?

Comment: @antlersoft yes, of course. I run make every time I make changes

Comment: Did you disable debug (#define NDEBUG or -dNDEBUG) when you compiled?

Comment: @theluckyemil That does say much. You really need to make sure your program loads the modified readline library at runtime, and not the system installed readline library. Please run  `ldd ./yourprogram` to check.

Comment: @nos I deleted the contents of /usr/include/readline so there is no way it can use system installed library.

Comment: @theluckyemil deleting /usr/include/readline doesn't help, that is just the header files, not the compiled library that's loaded at runtime. The library is probably located in /usr/lib/. Please run `ldd ./yourprogram` to see which library is used at runtime.

Comment: @nos it says:  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa6af4000)
 libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f940a6a7000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f940a2e1000)
 libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f940a0b7000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f940a910000)

Comment: @theluckyemil So you're likely using the system installed /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 when you execute your program, not the one you modified.

Comment: @nos and how can I fix that?

Comment: @atk no, I don't even know what it is.